# C# Ways to access containing class without passing reference

Tags: c#, reference, constructor, containers

Is there any way to access the containing/enclosing class during initialization (constructor logic) of the <strike>nested</strike> owned class without needing a reference passed as a constructor parameter?

**The reason I don't want to pass a reference** to the containing class as a constructor parameter to the <strike>nested</strike> owned class is because virtually every single object in my program would need it, and it just feels sloppy passing in an argument manually every time that would never change anyways. I want to simplify the programming as much as possible as other team members of mine will be using my engine.

**I tried** making a method for the container class to use when adding new objects that would take the new instance as a parameter and then set that instance's "container" variable to "this" (the container class), but the <strike>nested</strike> owned object's initialization code happens first which defeats the purpose (I want to be able to access the container during initialization, so the container variable needs to be set before, not after the constructor code is executed).

Any ways to make this happen? Or am I doomed to manually pass in a reference to the container class every time I make a new <strike>nested</strike> owned object?

**EDIT:**

**Example:**
Let's say I'm making a video game, and the player is going to cast a magic spell that spawns a HealerGoblin:

From Player class:

```
spawnMonster(new HealerGoblin(30)); //30 = Monster's Combat Level
```

In HealerGoblin class:

```
public HealerGoblin(int Level)
{
    Owner.Health += Level; //Owner in this case, being the player.
}
```

As you could probably see, the player would cast the spawn monster spell, select a level 30 healer goblin, and the healer goblin has a special effect when he spawns that increases his owner's health by some amount (in this case equal to the goblin's level). (**Keep in mind** this is a hypothetical, I know there are other, probably better, ways to do something like this specifically, but this is just an example of what I'm trying to do).

So the problem is, any player or NPC in the game could cast that spell and be the "owner". How would the goblin's Owner property be set by the time that initialization code that references the owner is executed?

**I know** I could pass the owner by reference:

```
spawnMonster(new HealerGoblin(this, 30); //First argument being what Owner is set to.
```

But I want every single object in my program to automatically have a reference to their "owners", and manually putting (this) every time I initialize a new object, and having to set up a new owner parameter to be passed every time I make a new derived class, just seems sloppy and counter-intuitive considering you would never not pass the reference.

**So my question is** what other ways would there be to do get a reference to the container/owner object before initialization besides passing it by reference through the constructor? If any?

Comment: For better answers, post the (simplified) class definitions. An 'embedded class' can mean different things, and the same for 'container class'.

Comment: @HenkHolterman "Nested class" in the context of C# means one thing and one thing only: a class that is a member of another type.

Comment: @cdhowie - yes, but I don't think the OP is talking about that.

Comment: Some type of dependency injection, perhaps? Like @HenkHolterman said, if you post a little code we might be able to better tell.

Comment: My bad, adding sample code now. Sorry if the terminology is off, it's been a while since I last worked on anything.

Comment: Right. This is not about 'nested classes; but about 'owned objects'.

Comment: Edited. Hopefully it's more clear now, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your pain. I've been there too. But the answer is no in a standard way of programming. It maybe possible by using the call stack, reflection and some hack work, but since you are trying to simplify your code, you don't want to have that kind of stuff in your code.

Comment: It is not possible with reflection. Reflection gets the metadata from an assembly. It can't help you to get the instance of class which called the method. I may be wrong. correct me if I am.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know. In short there is no such feature.